# I'm getting a "The parameter is Incorrect" error in a move file task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

All,

I've got a package that downloads Excel files from an FTP site then loads them to a table in SQL Server at at the end archives the files to another folder.

I've written packages like this hundreds of times, and in fact have similar packages running here now.

However with this particular package the archive task is failing with the error "The parameter is incorrect".

I've compared it to other similar packages and the set up is the same.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this.

I've got source, archive and filename as variables, and the foreachfile container works fine and loops through the files with no issues. It's simply the move file task that fails.

Here are some screen shots for clarity's sake:

Variables:

[image: Variables]

ForeachFile containier:

[image]

[image]
Move File:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution was to create a new data connection to the existing source directory and use that in the move file task along with the variable for the archive path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem my fix was to copy the file instead and add another task to the loop after that and delete the files

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well and found out that the "Destination" must not contain a file path but a folder path. But I guess it's not your case.

If that can help other people.

My source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6db138e2-bb24-41de-a28c-7c61eee59f31/filea-system-task-copy-works-but-move-fails?forum=sqlintegrationservices